# run multiple instances in the same server

Tags: docker

i want to run two instances of docker neo4j in the same computer.
i run

```
docker run --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 --volume=/Users/wangyiran/project/testplatformV6/data/neo4j1 neo4j:3.0
```

and another instance i want use different port and data directory.so i run

```
docker run --publish=7475:7475 --publish=7688:7688 --volume=/Users/wangyiran/project/testplatformV6/data/neo4j2 neo4j:3.0
```

but it doesn't work.
i knowledge docker can run multiple instances of the image,but how to do that?

Comment: What is your error message? (and docker version, and OS)

Comment: You use the same image for both containers so it's unlikely that the internal port numbers would be different (as your publish option assumes)

Comment: when i run the second port 7475,it message Remote interface available at http://0.0.0.0:7474/

Comment: @Henry so i should write another dockerfile of neo4j with different port?

Comment: No, just use the correct publish option to map the internal port used in the image to the host port you want to use. --publish=hostport:containerport

Comment: @Henry thanks very much,i really work!